# How to pass additional arguments for docker daemon

Tags: linux, docker, daemon

I have under `/etc/sysconfig/docker` , the following configuration :-

```
other_args="--insecure-registry ******* -g /apps/var/lib"
```

Now I am using docker version 17.03.1-ce on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.4 and default storage driver as overlay that is causing lot of build issues due to :-

```
checksum_type: too many links
```

After doing a bit of research on the internet figured out to get rid of this the best solution would be to use overlay2 driver.

How do i edit the `/etc/sysconfig/docker` to include storage driver as `overlay2`. I tried lot of ways but none worked.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated as always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a file /etc/docker/daemon.json with :-

{

"storage-driver": "overlay2",

"storage-opts": [

"overlay2.override_kernel_check=true"
] }

And that did the trick

Answer (score 0):

Based on [the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-storage-driver) you can pass `-s overlay2` to docker daemon.

your `other_args` should look like so:

```
other_args="--insecure-registry ******* -g /apps/var/lib -s overlay2"
```

Comment: That now results in error
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
if i remove that additional -s overlay2
then its back to working as usual with overlay as the storage driver

Answer (score -1):

I am using Docker Enterprise Edition on Red Hat Enterprise 7 so overlay is not supported, but in the Docker [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/#configure-docker-with-the-overlay-or-overlay2-storage-driver) for the Overlay File System, it says to add a section in the `/etc/docker/daemon.json` file (which I had to create). This [section](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/#configure-docker-with-the-overlay-or-overlay2-storage-driver) of the docs explains how to configure overlay2.

1. Stop docker by running `sudo systemctl stop docker`.
2. Create a backup of Docker's local storage (/var/lib/docker) by running `cp /var/lib/docker /var/lib/docker.backup`. The docs say:

   > If you want to use a separate backing filesystem from the one used by /var/lib/, format the filesystem and mount it into /var/lib/docker. Make sure add this mount to /etc/fstab to make it permanent.
3. Then edit `/etc/docker/daemon.json` after creating it (if it isn't already there). Add:

   ```
   {
       "storage-driver": "overlay2"
   }
   ```
4. Start docker with `sudo systemctl start docker`
5. Check to see if the file system changed by running `docker info` and checking the `storage driver` and `backing filesystem` sections

Comment: we don't want to alter the existing configuration, just need to somehow pass additional argument or so to switch the storage driver from overlay to overlay2. Please feel free to let me know if you need any specific details around our current docker configuration.